# Borrar varias imágenes con wScratchPad.js

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo un anuncio con el plugin wScratchPad.js para descubrir una promoción borrando la imagen de arriba.
El problema es que arriba de la imagen que se borra, he puesto texto y otras imagenes, y al tocar estos elementos, el fondo no se borra, ya que el usuario no está tocando directamente el fondo.

Supongo que lo que tendría que hacer es agregar estos elementos como variables, pero no sé cómo, ya que tengo poco conocimiento en Javascript, y estoy usando por primera vez este plugin. ¿Alguien podría indicarme dónde agregar las variables y cómo hacerlo?

Les dejo mi código:

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');
        var redirect= document.createElement('a');
        redirect.id="redirect";
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
  
     setTimeout(function(){
     $("#opacidad100").fadeTo(500,1);
        },500);
  
        setTimeout(function(){
     
      $("#celu").fadeTo(1000,1);
       $("#limpia").fadeTo(1000,1);
                $("#paravos").fadeTo(1000,1);
        },1000);
     
     
  
  
         setTimeout(function(){
    //$('#demo2').css({'opacity':'0'});
    $('#demo2').css({'opacity':'0'});
   //$("p").css({'color':'red','font-size':'1.3em','background':'yellow'});
   
        $('#demo2').wScratchPad({
          //bg: './images/winner.png',
    //bg: 'final.png',
          //fg: 'opacidad100.jpg',
    fg: 'opacidad100.jpg',
          'cursor': 'crosshair',
    'opacity':'0',
   
          scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
            $('#demo2-percent').html(percent);
   
              $('#demo2-percent').css({'opacity':'0'});
     
   if (percent > 1) {$('#info').css({'display':'none'});
                                                 $("#final").fadeTo(10,1);}
   
            if (percent > 50) {
   
    $('#demo2').fadeOut(500,0);
    content.appendChild(redirect);
             // this.clear();
     /* function clear() {
                 this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()), Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight()));
                }*/
            }
          }
        });
  
  setTimeout(function(){
  $("#demo2").fadeTo(500,1);
  },300);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
             $( "#hielo" ).fadeOut(500,0);
             },300);
   
       
  },500);
  
  });
  
  var clickTag = "";
     redirect.onclick = function(){
        window.open(clickTag, "blank")
        }
```

```html
     <div id="info">
       <img src="descubre-min.png" id="descubre" alt="descubre" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;z-index:50;margin-top:140px;left:50%;margin-left:-121px;"/>
    <img src="celu-min.gif" id="celu" alt="celu" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;z-index:50;margin-top:170px;left:33%;margin-left:-43px;height:200px"/>
    <img src="limpia.png" id="limpia" alt="limpia" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;z-index:50;margin-top:370px;left:75px;margin-left:-50px;"/>
    <img src="paravos.png" id="paravos" alt="paravos" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;z-index:50;margin-top:100px;left:33%;margin-left:-50px;"/>
     </div>
```

Comment: puedes "ocultar" los elementos superiores con css, añadiendo un `pointer-events:none` quizás así funcione?

Comment: @Adrián acabo de probar lo que sugeriste, y si, funciona perfectamente! Los elementos desaparecen en cuando toco sobre ellos. Gracias! Jamás se me hubiese ocurrido hacerlo con css!

Comment: Genial!, lo escribo como respuesta y no te olvides de marcarla como solucionada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a usar `pointer-events: none`, así podrás quitar los eventos de raton sobre esos objetos y te dejará usar lo que deseas